# how to prevent html page reload in django

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-views, django-templates

```
 <html>
<head>
</head>
<br>
<body>
<h2><center>Choose your pose</center></h2>  
<div><center>
<datalist id="languages">
<option value="dancers-pose">
<option value="mountain-pose">
<option value="pranamasana">
<option value="tree-pose">
<option value="triangle-pose">
<option value="warrior-pose"> 
</datalist>
<input type="text" id = "abc" list="languages">
<br>
<br>
</center>
</div>
<div>
<center>
<h2>Upload your image</h2> 
<form method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type = "file" name="document">
<br>
<button type = "submit">upload file</button>
</center>
</form>
</div>

<div>
<center>
<button type="button" onClick = "myFun()">Get Results</button> 
</center>
</div>

<script>
function myFun(){
var try_pose = document.getElementById("abc").value;
console.log(try_pose);
try_pose1 = try_pose + ".jpg";

console.log(try_pose1);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Above is my **html file**

```
def full(request):
if(request.method == 'POST'):
    files = glob.glob('media/*')
    for f in files:
        os.remove(f)

    uploaded_file = request.FILES['document']
    fs = FileSystemStorage()
   # uploaded_file.name = 'temp.jpg'
    fs.save(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file)
    path = "media" + "/" + uploaded_file.name
   # im = Image.open("media/temp.jpg")
    im = Image.open(path)    
    im = im.resize((620,620))
    width, height = im.size
    im= im.save("media/temp.jpg")

return render(request,'full.html')
```

Above code is present in my **views.py** .
When the image is submitted the data present in the textbox is lost may be because the page is reloaded. I request for a solution which might be a small change in the above code which would not reload the page so I can access the value of the textbox later inside the javascript function **myfun()**.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to reload the page on submission, you should use Ajax otherwise no proper solutions are available to prevent the page reload on form submit an event. Here is the video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KgnPSmrQrXI) for use ajax with form.

Comment: You can also use localstorage